# how to have a for loop for selected cells in UICollectionview

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

hello i am new to ios development so any help given is appreciated.
What I'm doing is I have an array of images (clothesToWear) that populates 5 different collectionViews and I am looping through the array to change the "hot" ones to "cold". That part is working fine (and done by a protocol if that helps). But what I want to do is only change those cells that have been selected and are dirty. I have tried several different ideas and just cant seem to find one that works.

Here is the code for the button:

```
@IBAction func cleanChecked(sender: AnyObject) {
    let cv = UICollectionView?()

    for cell in (cv?.visibleCells())! as [UICollectionViewCell] {
            for cItem in clothesToWear {

                //Comments are an idea that did not work 

                //let indexPaths : NSArray = cView1!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
                //let indexPath : NSIndexPath = indexPaths[0] as! NSIndexPath

                //if cItem.cState == .hot && self.firstView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)!.selected == true

                if cItem.cState == .hot && cell.selected == true {
                    cItem.cState = .cold
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the difference between cv and cView1? Why didn't you say cv.indexPathsForSelectedItems()?

Comment: cv is just a collectionview.. cView1 is the first of the 5 collectionviews.

Comment: Why are you using five different collection views? If you have 5 wouldn't you want to call indexPathsForSelectedItems() on all of them to get all of the selected items?